# How can prevent users in my GCP VM Instance to become root?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, root, sudoers

I created an Ubuntu VM on GCP Compute Engine.

Some details:

```
-> (ubuntu-minimal-2204-jammy-v20220810)

 Machine type
    e2-micro
CPU platform
    Intel Broadwell
Architecture
    x86/64
```

I added one user using SSH keys. This user can properly access to the VM, no problem here.
But he can also become root like this:

```bash
# he resets the root password
sudo passwd

# the he can become root using the freshly created password
su
```

How can I prevent this ?

I tried to remove this user from the `sudoers` but without success:

```bash
root@vm_test:/home/user# sudo deluser user_test sudo
/usr/sbin/deluser: The user `user_test' is not a member of group `sudo'.
```

EDIT:
My sudoers config file looks like this. I might modify it to restrict access. But I don't understand how.

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Details are missing in your post. In order to run `su passwd` to change the root user password, the user must have switched to the root user first. How was that done in your case?

Comment: @JohnHanley Indeed, I made a mistake. I just edited my question.

Comment: @cuzureau If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In IAM, give them `roles/compute.osLogin`, not `roles/compute.osAdminLogin` or `roles/compute.instanceAdmin`.

Comment: How can I find him in IAM ? I just added the SSH key of this user in the parameters of the VM. I cannot find him in IAM.

Answer (score 0):

The SSH Access method that you are using ([Manage SSH keys in metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/access-overview#ssh-access)) leverages the access management to a directory service; if you want to control the access level to your instance(s) using Google's Identity Service, you need to use the [OS Login method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/access-overview#oslogin) instead.

Here is an example granting normal user access to an instance named 'ubuntu-test' to the user 'test-user@gmail.com':

```
gcloud compute instances add-iam-policy-binding ubuntu-test \
    --member='user:test-user@gmail.com' \
    --role='roles/compute.osLogin' \
    --zone=<instance_zone>
```

Note: Unlike the Manage SSH key method, in the OS Login method the user must exist in the GCP database in order to properly assign the permissions.

Comment: Was this answer useful?